# C# Linq SelectMany, returning entire object

Tags: linq, silverlight-5.0, generic-collections

I have a class like this:

```
public class FileCollection:ObservableCollection<IUserFile>.
```

From within the class, I would like to get a subset of the collection, based on a list of names.

I imagine it would be something like this:

```
List<IUserFile> selectedFiles = new List<IUserFile>;
foreach(string s in names)  
{  
    var matchingFiles = this.SelectMany(userFile => userFile.Name.Equals(s));  
    foreach(IUserFile uf in matchingFiles)  
    {  
        selectedFiles.Add(uf);    
    }  
 }
```

At this point, I'm having trouble with the Select or SelectMany call; the compiler error messages are not that helpful.
Any suggestions on how to extract the subset from the collection would be appreciated...

Comment: Although I know it might look like `SelectMany` should "select many" of the source, actually what you want is `Where`. `SelectMany` is for when for each item in the source you want to select many *other* things (eg from a list of parents, you might `SelectMany` to produce a list of children).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb534803.aspx) instead - which "Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate" - such that:

```
var matches = this.Where(userFile => userFile.Name.Equals(s));
```

Rather than [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534336.aspx), which "Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence."

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I just discovered that this.Where() is exactly what I'm looking for.